# C# - Converting a string to a float array and ignoring special characters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a dirt-simple program to convert a string like "[0.00, 2277, 1827, 1840, 1, 1247, 1238, 993]" to a numeric array that I can then do some math on. However, I'm getting an error that the "Input string was not in a correct format".

Could someone point out where I've gone wrong? Sorry, I'm a total beginner here.

```
using System;

namespace ColorConverter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter color cal curve: ");
            string input12BitLine = Console.ReadLine();

            float[] fltCalTable = Array.ConvertAll(input12BitLine.Split('[', ' ', ',', ']'), float.Parse); //error is here

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The input here appears to be JSON. So why not use a JSON parser to deserialize this to a float[] for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks like you are passing JSON array as an input. Use JSON parser to parse input string to [`JArray`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Parse.htm) and then convert each element to float.

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
 ....
 var result = JArray.Parse(input12BitLine).Select(x => x.Value<float>());
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

---

**Alternate solutions**

You are getting this error because it is trying to parse empty strings which are generating after splitting the array by `'[', ' ', ',', ']'`. If you want to use all these delimiters, then use [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-5.0) to remove empty strings from an array.

```
float[] fltCalTable = Array.ConvertAll(input12BitLine.Split(new char[] {'[', ' ', ',', ']'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), float.Parse);
```

---

You need to `Trim` square brackets first and then convert to Float by splitting each element using `,` as delimiter

```
//Readable solution
string input12BitLine = Console.ReadLine();
var floatArray = input12BitLine.Trim(new char[]{ '[', ']'}) //Remove square brackets
    .Split(',')   //Split string by ','
    .Select(float.Parse)  //Parse each element to float
    .ToArray();   //Convert to Array
```

Or using `Array.ConvertAll()`

```
float[] fltCalTable = Array.ConvertAll(input12BitLine.Trim(new char[]{ '[', ']'}).Split(','), float.Parse);
```

---

POC: [.NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d4sIma)

Comment: OP is trying to parse JSON by hand... Really not sure why you supporting them in that strange journey.

Comment: is it? I can see OP is reading string from console? yeah OP might be typing JArray on console\

Comment: I agree that it is super unusual to have "[ ]" in input that typed by a user... but that's what OP asks for...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I updated my answer to use `JArray` and convert it to float

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the empty strings.

```
float[] fltCalTable = Array.ConvertAll(input12BitLine.Split('[', ' ', ',', ']').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)).ToArray(), float.Parse);
```

Comment: You can use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` enum value instead of Where clause. It will improve your linq query by skipping one more for loop